# How much did King George III of Britain weigh?

Tags: british-empire, britain

I cannot, for the life of me, find out how much King George III of Britain weighs. I would like to know his physical stature, as I am making a rhythmic poem with my class.

Comment: Are you expecting him to weigh the same amount his entire life?

Comment: No, I just want to know what he weighed at his peak

Comment: I really wonder what rhythmic poem requires such knowledge...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rather precise measurement *for one specific point in time* would be:

> He had a decided pyknic habitus—according to the work of Kretschmer, the usual body build for the manic depressive patient.
> He was five feet ten and one-half inches tall, and in his fifth decade weighed two hundred and ten pounds. He was muscular rather than fat. He had blonde hair; fair ruddy skin; a prominent nose and grey eyes.
>
> — Manfred S. Guttmacher. "The "Insanity" of George III", Bulletin of the Menninger Clinic; Topeka, Kan., Vol. 28, No. 3,  (May 1, 1964): p101. ([proQuest](https://www.proquest.com/scholarly-journals/insanity-george-iii/docview/1298135141/))